# exports kernel Windows for informations on hardware

Tags: c++, hardware, driver, kernel, security

Good day! I develop small security software and use a driver like any modern security software. Can you please tell me if there are any exported functions from ntoskrnl.exe or hal.dll or other kernel mode modules to get the PC hardware ID. It seems that game programs use such approaches for deanonymization...

Comment: Are you looking for this information 

    powershell -c "Get-CimInstance Win32_PhysicalMedia" | grep -iE "tag|serial"

Comment: yes, but is it possible to get it using any api kernels?